# Trying to search Mlabs with Angular2 service but URL route not found

Tags: angular, mean-stack, mlab

I already have my local mongodb working fine with expressjs but I want to connect MLABS to my app too. I set up the following to interact with MLABs:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const MLABS = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
const MONGO_URL = 'MY MONGO MLABS HERE';
var global = new MLABS();
```

Here I connect to MLABS, this works fine:

```
global.connect(MONGO_URL, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.error("Error! " + err);
    }else{
        console.log("Connected to online server");
    }
});
```

Now ive set up the following URL below to search a collection in mongo
// Getting searched user from database

```
global.get('/globalusers/:username', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("gothere!!!");
    var username = req.params.username;
    console.log(username);
    Profile.find({username: username}, function (err, messages) {
        console.log(messages);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error while fetching data!'
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            data: messages
        });    
    });
});
```

I have the following service set up in anuglar2 which is meant to contact the route above to GET json from MLABS:

```
searchUsers(user: string) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/globalusers/' + user )
            .map( (data: Response) => {
                const extracted = data.json();
                const msgArray: Profile[] = [];
                let message;
                for (let element of extracted.data) {
                    console.log(element.firstName);
                    message = new Profile(element.username, element.aboutMe, element.avatar, element.statusCount ,element.friendCount,element.isOnline,element.bitcoinAddress,element.email,element.lat,element.long);
                    msgArray.push(message);
                }
                return msgArray;
            });
    }
```

this is the problem, I get a 404 error status saying this route does not exist when I call it even thought ive double checked that they are the same?

Using the expressjs router to trigger a GET to MLABs using a Mongoose instance:

```
// Getting crypto profile from db
router.get('/globalusers/:username', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("gothere!!!");
    var username = req.params.username;
    console.log(username);
    // Getting searched user from database
    global.get('/globalusers/' + username, function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(username);
        console.log(this.username);
        Profile.find({username: username}, function (err, messages) {
            console.log(messages);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error while fetching data!'
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                data: messages
            });    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You never define a route. `global` is a Mongoose object, not an Express app. It looks like you want to use `app.get()` to define a route (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get), instead you're running the `get` method on a Mongoose object, which doesn't do what you want it to do. If you want to have a webserver, use Express. Mongoose just talks to the database, it doesn't have anything to do with defining routes.

Comment: @tfogo I've tried to take what you explained to me into account and Ive edited the post to include the router in the mlabs GET request, the Angular2 service does find the route and the got there and username console.logs are triggered but then my call to global is completly ignored? whys that?

Comment: The updated code is still running `global.get`. `global` is a Mongoose object and its `get` method doesn't work like that. You cannot define a route on a Mongoose object - it doesn't make any sense. I highly recommend going through a tutorial (this is a good one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction) and reading the Mongoose and Express Quick Starts until you understand what's wrong with your code above. You may also find this example Express/Mongoose app useful: https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038

Comment: I got it working using the mongo client to deal with MLABs and using expressjs for my local database